# Change origin position in ios-charts

Tags: ios-charts

Has anyone tried setting a custom origin (0,0) for ios-charts?

The default origin is at the bottom left corner, I want my origin at the top left corner, is this possible? (see images for reference)

default

[image: default origin]

what i want to achieve

[image: what i want to achieve]

Answer (score 1):

You can change label position for `XAxis` instance object using your chartView object.

```
//self.chartView is the ChartView instance.
let  xAxis : XAxis = self.chartView.xAxis
xAxis.labelPosition = .top
```

Comment: 'labelPosition' only changes the position of the axis label. the origin position is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.

First, as another answer said, change `xAxis.labelPosition = .top`.

Then, set Y axis `self.chartView.leftAxis.inverted = true`.

That`s all!